# jquery variable values bleeding

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

i am totally missing something here. I need to define a base variable. Then reference that base varialbe in a series of second variables. Each of the second variables will be provided alternate values. However I am seeing the modified values bleed back to the base variablle

for example

```
<script>
var a = [{a:1}];
var b = a;
b.a = 22;
alert('a-a equals' + a.a + ' and b-a equals ' + b.a);
</script>
```

I want a.a to equal 1 and b.a to equal 22. however I am seeing both equal 22. Can someone explain what I am missing?

Comment: When you assign arrays or objects, you're just assigning references to the same thing, not making a copy.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference. When you do `var b = a`, since `a` is an array and arrays are objects, the array is passed by reference so `b` references the same array as `a`. Instead, you need to create a copy of `a` and store that in `b`.

Comment: Also, I think you mean `a[0].a` and `b[0].a`.

Comment: how do I go about making the copy of a I tried new ( b = new a;) but get an error saying a is not a function

Comment: No i guess he means `a[0].a and b.a` @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var b = a;` this will just copy the reference to the actual array (*The array will not be copied*)

You can copy your array like this -

```
var a1 = [{a:1}];
var a2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a1));
a2[0].a = 22;
console.log('a-a equals' + a1[0].a + ' and b-a equals ' + a2[0].a);
```

Or -

```
var a2 = $.map(a1, function (obj) {
    return $.extend({}, obj);
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/vTpSk/

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the fact that `var b = a;` doesn't create a new copy of `a` into `b`, it actually assigns the **reference** of the object stored in `a` into `b`.  What this means is  that any actions you take against the object stored in `b` is happening to the object stored in `a` at the same time.  That is because in reality they are the EXACT SAME object!

`a` and `b` are really just telling the code where it can find the underlying object in memory, and in this case they are both pointing to the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will not clone a reference type when you assign a to b.  There are ways to do this if you want using [jquery clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) or [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

for example, you could do

```
var a = $.extend({}, a, b);
```

Comment: `a` is an array, `$.extend` is for objects.

Comment: @Barmar however, it will work, if you also use `$.makeArray` http://jsfiddle.net/e9Lja/1/

Answer (score 0):

Objects are passed by reference. When you do `var b = a`, since `a` is an array and arrays are objects, the array is passed by reference so `b` references the same array as `a`. Instead, you need to create a copy of `a` and store that in `b`.

To copy an array, you would just use `a.slice(0)`

```
// NOTE! this example doesn't work, explained below.
var a = [{a:1}];
var b = a.slice(0);
b[0].a = 22;
alert('a-a equals' + a[0].a + ' and b-a equals ' + b[0].a);
```

**However**, since your array contains an object, the object inside the array still references the same object! Therefore, you're going to have to instead loop over the array, re-creating the array from the inside out. jQuery's $.extend method can be used here:

```
var a = [{a:1}];
var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b.push( $.extend({},a[i]) );
}
b[0].a = 22;
alert('a-a equals ' + a[0].a + ' and b-a equals ' + b[0].a);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e9Lja/

an alternative is to use jquery's `$.extend` combined with `$.makeArray`:

```
var a = [{a:1}];
var b = $.makeArray($.extend({},a));
b[0].a = 22;
alert('a-a equals ' + a[0].a + ' and b-a equals ' + b[0].a);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e9Lja/1/

though, i prefer the for loop or $.map(see pXL's answer) because `$.extend` isn't meant for copying arrays.